# Gnome Fallback - Menu With Search

Tags: gnome-classic

Does Gnome 3 Fallback have GnomeShell-like menu with appsearch?
I like Cardapio, But it not work as panel applet.

Comment: by default no But i search and saw addons like this but can't used it because it's need to compile and i'm not programmer but you can do temp solution is press Alt + f2 a window will show in it you will see small arrow press it and write name of any program you wanna it i'm using this now

Answer (score 0):

Not certain this is a direct answer - Alt-right click   Add to panel  search is available